# Window function with a limit clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Given this dataset of teams

```
id | team_name | points
1  | A         | 10
2  | B         | 20
3  | C         | 30
4  | D         | 40
5  | E         | 50
```

i can use this query with a window function to get the average of the top 3 teams

```
with top_3 as(
  select * 
  from teams 
  order by points desc 
  limit 3
)

select *, avg(points) over() as top3_average
from top_3
```

Is is possible to use window functions on only the top 3 rows from the dataset?

I tried with, but that certainly doesn't work.

```
OVER(... limit 3)
```

Here is a working [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/badc9/2)

---

*Just to be clear I know I can do this with a subquery like so. I'm more interested in learning if this is possible with a window function*

```
select *, avg(points) over() as top3_average
from teams
where id in
  (select id 
   from teams 
   order by points desc 
   limit 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.  You can't easily specify a FRAME that only includes the first three rows.  You could get the average in the first row and put nulls everywhere else, but this just seems like a terrible idea:

```
select *, 
    avg(points) OVER (ORDER BY points desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING) 
    * CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (ORDER BY points desc) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END
FROM teams;
 id | team_name | points |      ?column?
----+-----------+--------+---------------------
  6 | F         |     60 | 50.0000000000000000
  5 | E         |     50 |
  4 | D         |     40 |
  3 | C         |     30 |
  2 | B         |     20 |
  1 | A         |     10 |
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

yes possible use `row_number()` window function

```
with top_3 as(
  select * ,row_number() over(order by points desc) rn 
  from teams 


) select * form top_3 where rn<=3
```

[fiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/badc9/3)